# Data Scraping XPath span returns no value

Tags: python, html, xpath, web-scraping

I am trying to retrieve helpfulness indicators from an online review website. Using Python and lxml i try to retrieve this value, however the output remains empty. I used the following code and corresponding XPath:

`span class="brand-find-useful__count">1</span>`

`tree = html.fromstring(page)
helpfulness = tree.xpath('//span[@class="brand-find-useful__count"]/text()')`

However, it just doesn't give me an output, just an empty value. Important to note that when no thumbs up (useful) have been given, this span doesn't show up. I tried several times know on a page that definitely has useful counts, but unfortunately i can't retrieve it. I am still a novice but i have no idea were the mistake is.

Comment: `tree.xpath('//span[@class="brand-find-useful__count"]/text()')` returns a list, you can use `tree.xpath('//span[@class="brand-find-useful__count"]/text()')[0]` to get the text.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. If i do this i get: 'IndexError: list index out of range'.

Comment: Hi @Principia, welcome to Stack Overflow! :-). I'm not sure about XML and websites. HTML is not XML and that can cause some issues for you. Maybe the Beautiful Soup library is a better fit? It allows querying the HTML tree using CSS selectors ( https://riptutorial.com/python/example/4510/using-css-selectors-in-beautifulsoup )

Comment: Thanks @mhogerheijde for the welcome and suggestion. I will look into it. I started with the xpath approach and thought, maybe there is a way i can solve it via that. Will look into Beautiful Soup, thanks.

Comment: What's the url?

Comment: Hi @JackFleeting . See for instance the following page: https://www.trustpilot.com/review/www.trivago.co.uk?page=4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong *xpath*, `//span[@class="brand-find-useful__count"]/text()` is not a valid xpath as it only appears if you have a JavaScript rendered output. You could verify this by just looking at the page source in your browser (not using devtools)

```
view-source:https://www.trustpilot.com/review/www.trivago.co.uk?page=4
```

You will also find script tags with json data of the reviews in *view-source*, you could take that json string instead of taking data from elements. I would leave that to you to check.

The below code shows you how to take the helpfulness count from the page.

***Solution***

```
import requests
from lxml import html

response = requests.get('https://www.trustpilot.com/review/www.trivago.co.uk?page=4')

tree = html.fromstring(response.text)

# fetches all useful elements 
useful = tree.xpath('//brand-find-useful-button')

# loop through each element
for e in useful:
  print(e.get(':initial-find-useful-count'))
```

***Output***

```
1
1
0
1
0
2
2
1
2
0
1
0
0
1
1
1
1
1
1
```

See this in action [here](https://repl.it/repls/FaintTechnologicalAbility).

Comment: Wow great, that definitely worked! One small question concerning this - while i indeed see the output in Python, when i look at the list it shows "HtmlElement" rather than the number. Do i need to add something to the script to transform the value "HtmlElement" to the corresponding numeral output? In the long run i want to run the script over several pages and thus append it al.

Comment: @Principia `useful` is a list of HTMLElements, since the value is present in the attribute we can't just use `text()` or `.text`. You can append `e.get(':initial-find-useful-count')` to a list for later usage.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `select` and then extract the relevant attribute.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

r = requests.get('https://www.trustpilot.com/review/www.trivago.co.uk?page=4')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')

for review in soup.select('.review'):
    useful = review.select_one('brand-find-useful-button')
    print(useful[':initial-find-useful-count'])
```

Comment: HTML nor XML are regular languages. I would advise *against* using regular expressions to parse HTML (or XML) since you will be chasing unsolvable bugs rather sooner than later.

Comment: @mhogerheijde I am not parsing html per se with regex. I am parsing a string. I was very specific in ensuring I was working with a particular string as well. The html is parsed with bs4 as is the node matching.

Comment: You are interpreting a string representation of the tag, right? In my book that is parsing. Correct me if I'm wrong but the result of `str(useful)` is `<brand-find-useful-button :initial-find-use … d5f1">`. The regular expression checks if the text contains some attribute with a numerical value. Why not use BS to get the attribute and its value?

Comment: That last part is actually a good point and I missed it so thank you. Updated.